# How to improve Volatile GPU-Util?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Using Keras to train model, Volatile GPU-Util of two GPU is too low.
[image]

The block of code:

```
%%time
np.random.seed(seed)

model_d2v_01 = Sequential()
model_d2v_01.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=400))
model_d2v_01.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_d2v_01 = multi_gpu_model(model_d2v_01, gpus=2)
model_d2v_01.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='adam',
                       metrics=['accuracy'])

model_d2v_01.fit(train_vecs_dbow_dmm, y_train, validation_data=(validation_vecs_dbow_dmm, y_validation), epochs=5, batch_size=32*2, verbose=2)
```

How to modify this code? some suggestion, please.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this situation was normal. The cause was from few layers, so the model was too simple. when add more model layer, this situation will improve. for example:

```
%%time
np.random.seed(seed)
# with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
model_d2v_12 = Sequential()
model_d2v_12.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=400))
model_d2v_12.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model_d2v_12.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model_d2v_12.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_d2v_12 = multi_gpu_model(model_d2v_12, gpus=2)
model_d2v_12.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='adam',
                       metrics=['accuracy'])

model_d2v_12.fit(train_vecs_dbow_dmm, y_train, validation_data=(validation_vecs_dbow_dmm, y_validation), epochs=10, batch_size=2048*2, verbose=2)
```